# conemu: Can I disable the scroll bar?

Tags: conemu

I don't want to disable scrolling I just want to disable the scroll bar, is this possible?

I like doing ctrl+ to scroll up and down, but I don't like that the scroll bar rears its ugly head when I do this- it obstructs the text in the terminal.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, you can.

1. Press <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> to open the settings
2. Navigate to the **Main > Appearence** tab
3. Inside the **Scrollbar** section, select the **Hide** radio button
4. Click **Save Settings**

Comment: Muwahahaha! I've almost reached desktop perfection, just a few more tweaks and I'm there, just a few more tweaks and then I'll stop and get back to work, just a _few_ _more_ _tweaks_...

Comment: @user1028270 hahaha I can relate to that too well...